# How to create JavaScript variables for use with TypeScript generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have a TypeScript file:

```
export class Table<T> {
    private readonly records: Record<string, T> = {};
}

export function foo(table: Table<number>) {
    console.log('Foo');
}
```

And I have a JavaScript file

```
import { Table, foo } from './scratch';

let table = new Table();
foo(table);
```

The `table` argument in `foo(table)` is underlined yellow with the warning

```
Argument type Table  is not assignable to parameter type Table
...
    Type Record  is not assignable to type Record
    Type unknown is not assignable to type number
```

How can I make the IDE (WebStorm) not yell at me about this (preferably through code changes and not IDE settings)?

Answer (score 0):

One way (but not necessarily the optimal way) is to extend the generic class with a typed version before using it in JavaScript:

```
export class Table<T> {
    private readonly records: Record<string, T> = {};
}

export class NumberTable extends Table<number> {}
```

It's not fool-proof since it does require modifying the TypeScript source instead of typing the JavaScript source, but it does the trick.